# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Estou criando uma classe para realizar querys no banco, mas estou tendo o seguinte erro quando eu tenho usar prepared statements:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MinhasFuncoes\php\model.php on line 13

Onde posso estar errando? Pensei ser o construtor, mas aparentemente não é.

Index:

```
<?php
require_once 'model.php';
 $conn = new model("mysql","localhost", "teocratico", "UTF8","root","");
 $conn->consulta("descricao","desafios");
?>
```

Classe:

```
 <?php
    class model {
      private $conexao;

      public function __construct ($db, $host, $dbname, $charset, $usuario, $senha){
        try{
          $this->conexao = new PDO ("$db:host=$host; dbname=$dbname; charset=$charset","$usuario","$senha");
        } catch (PDOException $erro){
            return $erro->getmessage();
        }
      }
      public function consulta ($campos, $tabela){
        $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT :campos FROM :tabela"); //erro nessa linha
        $this->conexao->BindParam(':campos', $campos);
        $this->conexao->BindParam(':tabela', $tabela);
        $this->conexao->execute();
        $resultado = $this->conexao->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $resultado;
      }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Antes da linha 13, faca: `echo $campos." - ".$tabela; die();`

Veja o que traz em campos e tabela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar o try/catch dentro do construtor já não parece bom e ainda mais usar `return` nele, isso não irá funcionar, é melhor que use o try/catch fora da classe, pois assim ao menos terá um uso sensato para eles, já que usar um try/catch apenas para checar o PDO e não parar o resto do que deveria fazer parte do "mesmo" bloco não tem muito sentido

Então pra explicar melhor, creio que o problema esta ocorrendo na conexão e como usou o try/catch não emite nada e nem finaliza o script e como eu disse o `return` "não funciona" no `__construct`, então em seguida você tenta usar o método `consulta`, mas a variável `$this->conexao` não passou pelo `try` por alguma falha na chamada do `new PDO`, então ela ainda estava `NULL`.

você passou também o `bindParam` na conexão ao invés de usar no `prepare` e no `execute`:

```
$this->conexao->prepare("SELECT :campos FROM :tabela"); //erro nessa linha
$this->conexao->BindParam(':campos', $campos);
$this->conexao->BindParam(':tabela', $tabela);
```

Deveria ser isto:

```
$prepare = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT :campos FROM :tabela"); //erro nessa linha
$prepare->BindParam(...);
$prepare->BindParam(...);
```

Outro problema que o Rray me atentou foi o uso dos parametros para o `FROM` e colunas, não tem como isto funcionar da maneira que você fez, o `bindParam` e `bindValue` funcionam como escapadores de caracteres, na verdade os parametros depois de processados ficariam algo como:

```
SELECT 'id, nome, senha' FROM 'minhatabela'
```

Ou seja query não vai procurar `minhatabela` no banco, ele vai procurar `'minhatabela'` com os apóstrofos incluídos e ao invés de procurar a 3 colunas ele vai procurar **gerar** uma coluna com o nome `id, nome, senha`, como se fosse tudo uma coisa só.

Sugiro mudar para isto:

```
<?php
class model {
  private $conexao;

  public function __construct ($db, $host, $dbname, $charset, $usuario, $senha){
        $this->conexao = new PDO ("$db:host=$host; dbname=$dbname; charset=$charset","$usuario","$senha");
  }

  public function consulta (array $campos, $tabela){
    $prepare = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT ' . $campos . ' FROM " . $tabela);

    $prepare->execute();

    $resultado = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($resultado);
  }
}
```

E na chamada:

```
require_once 'model.php';

try{
    $conn = new model("mysql","localhost", "teocratico", "UTF8","root","");
    $conn->consulta("descricao","desafios");
} catch (PDOException $erro){
    echo $erro->getmessage();
}
```

Claro que não deve passar acesso ao controle de `$campos` e `$tabela` ao usuário final por GET e POST, de resto uso o `bindParam` lembrando que ele sempre "escapa" os caracteres e "adiciona os apóstrofos" no processamento

Comment: Acredito o que bind desse (pergunta) código não funciona, tem na lista de campos e no nome da tabela.

Comment: Isso mesmo, `SELECT :campos FROM :tabela`

Comment: @rray opa, falta corrigir alguns detalhes, edição precipitada :p

Comment: Haha o primeiro comentário meu ficou bem ruim. Quis dizer que os binds se aplicam apenas em valores (exceto alguns hacks) e não em nomes de tabelas ou lista de campos. A correção do `prepare()` também é importante.

Comment: @rray eu testei e entedi, tinha me esquecido dos "escapar" das instruções preparadas, editado e obrigado ;)

Comment: Tô realizando alguns testes, já dou o retorno se funcionou. Obrigado desde já :)

Comment: Funcionou, mas faltou o `execute`, como eu implemento o bindParam dessa forma então? Ou como eu trato para evitar SQLinjection? Uma hora o dado enviado pelo usuário vai chegar na query :/

Comment: @TiagoSilveira você quer mesmo passar colunas e o controle das tabelas para o usuário final?